# Intel HD Graphics Error Code 43 when doing GVT-g "passthrough"

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, arch-linux

I've managed to setup Intel GVT-g on my machine using this guide: https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/8h352p/guide_running_windows_via_qemukvm_and_intel_gvtg/

I was also able work to the point [from the steps] to install Windows, but instead of Windows 8.1, I installed Windows 10, the Basic Driver works but the connected and shared Host GPU, Intel HD Graphics [530] returns error 403,

**what could be missing here?**

Update:

When I install Windows 8 run it and install the Intel HD driver, the VM throws:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: vfio_region_write(7fd737cf-92f7-43e0-92ce-ee034fb69d70:region0+0x2230, 0xe1514119,4) failed: Bad address
```

Comment: Are you installing the correct version?

Comment: @ChanganAuto Version of?

Comment: Why are you not just installing the Intel Windows 10 display drivers? 403 basically means based on my past research “not supported”.